# Static methods can't run other methods?

Tags: java, methods, static

So, I'm trying to make an extremely simple program.

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Yum! Pi!");
        int pi = 1;
        varCreate();
        varAdd();
    }
    public void varCreate () {
        pi++;
    }
    public void varAdd () {
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
}
```

It's wont let me do this, it says something along the lines of:
"cannot make static reference to the non-static method varAdd from the type test"
I'm sure there's an extremely simple error, I just can't find it. Kudos for any help!

Comment: make both varCreate() and varAdd() static as well and you should be good to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

static methods can only call static methods.

Either make the functions static or create an instance variable to call the methods.

```
public class test {
    static int pi = 1;
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Yum! Pi!");
        varCreate();
        varAdd();
    }
    public static void varCreate () {
        pi++;
    }
    public static void varAdd () {
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oof. Shoulda thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Still won't work of course since `int pi` is only declared within the scope of `main`....

Comment: Added code by making `pi` static as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate your Test class to use (non-static) methods:

```
class Test {
    int pi = 1;

    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Yum! Pi!");
        Test t = new Test();
        t.varCreate();
        t.varAdd();
    }
    public void varCreate () {
        pi++;
    }
    public void varAdd () {
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
}
```

`